# What is meant by a scalar function on a metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Say that I have the metric $(X,d)$. Then what is meant by a scalar function on a metric space? I think that it has to be either
$$
f:X \to X
$$
$$
x \mapsto \lambda x,
$$
for some scalar $\lambda$, or a map of the form
$$
f: X \to \mathbb{R}.
$$

Could someone clarify this for me?

Comment: the first variant will not work for all metric spaces.

Comment: Hi, could you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: Also may I ask why is this post getting downvoted? I believe I am following the outlined guidelines and this has not been asked here before.

Comment: Sorry, this website is very hostile to most questions. It's an unfortunate reality of the community here. As for your question, the first map $x\mapsto \lambda x$ is not a true map. The problem is with the expression $\lambda x$. Since $X$ is an arbitrary metric space (for example, $X=\{a,b\}$ with $d(a,b)=1$), the expression $\lambda x$ cannot be made sense of (eg. what could $5\times a$ possibly mean?). If you're trying to understand 'scalar function' from a textbook, you should include an image or a reference so that we may interpret the source for you.

Comment: Hi, no worries. This is Q7 from http://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/study/IB/AnalysisandTopology/2021-2022/sheet1.pdf. The issue is that the course has no official notes.

Comment: In general "scalar" refers to elements of an understood field associated with the context. Generally if the field isn't obvious from the context, it will mean the real numbers $\Bbb R$. I can only assume that your source (which I cannot access) was referring to a function from $X \to \Bbb R$.

Comment: Tried the link again, and this time it went through. They are talking about functions into $\Bbb R$.